# activerecord comparing times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, datetime-comparison

i am trying to do a query that will be compare the time stored in the database to the current time, and if it is greater than today to display those records.

below is query i am currently using that isnt displaying any records

```
@schedules = Schedule.where(:team_id => current_user[:team_id], :event => '1', :time => ">= Time.now.zone")
```

how do i go back query against a timestamp? so that these records will be displayed?

have also tried the following

```
@schedules = Schedule.find_all_by_team_id_and_event_and_time(current_user[:team_id],"1", :time)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@schedules = Schedule.where("team_id = ? and event = ? and time >= ?", [current_user[:team_id], "1", Time.zone.now])
```

The string is used directly in the SQL query so you need to make sure the column names are correct and unambiguous *(if you joined on another table that also has a `team_id` colum, you would need to do `schedules.team_id = ? and ...`)*

Comment: our time is stored like 'Mon, 06 Aug 2012 01:09 am' which i think is causing some issues, if there a way to compare this to the current time?

Comment: Why is your time stored that way? Is it not a timestamp or datetime field? If it's just a string the SQL is more complex to convert the string to a date for comparison. Dates/times should really be stored in a column with a type the rdbms interprets as date/time.

Comment: hi deefour it was store that way so that when we used the jquery time/date picker it would save

Comment: i have changed our field time to timestamp, though the issue I have now is that I cannot render it to be displayed nicely